# How to hide notification details in lock screen

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications

there is a requirement in my plate to hide notification details in the lock screen programmatically.

There is an option to achieve this by managing notification settings at the android phone level.

general notification be like below
[image: general notification be like below]

In phone settings, we have this option to hide notification details on the lock screen.

[image: In phone settings, we have this option to hide notification details on the lock screen.]

I got this notification (Excepted output)

after **hide details in settings** [image: I got this notification (Excepted output)]

I need to achieve this excepted output programmatically.

After my investigation, I found something,
while creating a notification builder, we have a choice to set visibility to the builder

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, selectedChannel).apply {
            setContentTitle(title)
            setContentText(body)
            setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
```

> ```
>     setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE) is a way to get custimization of notification visibility.
> ```

It doesn't fulfill my requirements, need suggestions/ opinions to complete my requirement

Comment: Hey did you find the solution?

Comment: NO @MuhammadAdeelShoukat

Comment: Hey @Barath I found solution if you set Visibility Secret instead of Private it will not show on locked screen.